# Why 'sort' in bash gives different ouputs in different machines?

Tags: bash, sorting

I tried command 'sort' in two virtual machines, but one gave all upper-case words before all lower-case words, and another sort in an ignore-case way.

**Not ignore case:**

```
[@sjs_100_189 tanglianrui]# sort test.txt 
A
T
a
b
t
```

**Ignore case:**

```
[@sjs_88_171 sortedOutput]# sort -f test.txt 
a
A
c
t
T
```

I'd like to know if there is a config file controlling the behavior of sort? If so, which one is it and how to config it? Thank you so much.

Comment: FYI, `sort` is not actually part of bash, and behaves identically no matter which shell it's started from or if it's run without any shell involved as all -- it's better tagged as `unix`.

Comment: As for your immediate question, look at the configured character collation order (`LC_COLLATE`, or, if that's not defined, `LC_ALL`). If you want simple ASCII sorting, `export LC_COLLATE=C` is appropriate.